# jQuery maths using PHP/MySQL values

Tags: jquery, mysql, math

I am trying to subtract a percentage from a number and have it display in an input using jQuery, but the form is pulling in values using PHP/MySQL.

I'm using an extra attribute on the select field because the value is a unique ID to be posted back to a different table on the database, this is what I have:

```
<input type="text" id="invamount" name="invamount" value="250.00"/>
<select id="invdiscount">
    <option data-discount="0" value="" selected>No Discount</option>
    <option data-discount="5" value="1">Discount 1 - 5%</option>
    <option data-discount="10" value="2">Discount 2 - 10%</option>
    <option data-discount="15" value="3">Discount 3 - 15%</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="invtotal" name="invtotal" />

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#invtotal").on("click", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
            var amount = document.getElementById('invamount').value;
            var discount = jQuery("#invdiscount option").attr("data-discount");
            var maths1 = (discount * amount/100);
            document.getElementById('invtotal').value = maths1;
        }
</script>
```

There are no errors in the console when loading the form but each time I select a different discount, the value of the total input just stays at 0.

Comment: can you not  let PHP put an extra attribute in the options tag? (eg. data-discount="") and than read that value with jQuery?

Comment: good idea, let me try it.

Comment: FYI, you can always make extra attributes, from html5 it is officialy supported with the naming convention that custom attributes should start their name with data-

Comment: Have edited the original question which now uses the newly created data-discount attribute because nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: I have amended the original script again as I have simplified the jquery, when I set the output (last line) to the var amount, 250.00 appears in the input which would be correct, when I set it to var discount then 0 appears when No discount is selected but when another is selected, it stays at 0, therefore if I set it to var maths1 as it is in the example, the maths wont work.

Comment: add an event to #invdiscount onChange do sum(), that's the problem, you are doing it on click#invtotal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not getting the discount attribute properly.
If you inspect the value of discount variable after the execution of the following line:

```
var discount = jQuery("#invdiscount option").attr("data-discount");
```

It will always return "0", because `jQuery("#invdiscount option")` is selecting all the options from the select box, not the *selected* one.

To get the discount attribute from the selected option, you can use `jQuery("#invdiscount option:selected").attr("data-discount")` (Note the :*selected* after *option*).

Also, if you want to get the input updated after selecting the option, you should listen for the *change* event in the *select* element.

The working code would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="invamount" name="invamount" value="250.00"/>
<select id="invdiscount">
    <option data-discount="0" value="" selected>No Discount</option>
    <option data-discount="5" value="1">Discount 1 - 5%</option>
    <option data-discount="10" value="2">Discount 2 - 10%</option>
    <option data-discount="15" value="3">Discount 3 - 15%</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="invtotal" name="invtotal" />

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#invdiscount").on("change", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
            var amount = document.getElementById('invamount').value;
            var discount = jQuery("#invdiscount option:selected").attr("data-discount");
            var maths1 = (discount * amount/100);
            document.getElementById('invtotal').value = maths1;
        }
</script>
```

Finally, you could use jQuery methods to get and and assign values instead of using plain javascript. The code would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="invamount" name="invamount" value="250.00"/>
<select id="invdiscount">
    <option data-discount="0" value="" selected>No Discount</option>
    <option data-discount="5" value="1">Discount 1 - 5%</option>
    <option data-discount="10" value="2">Discount 2 - 10%</option>
    <option data-discount="15" value="3">Discount 3 - 15%</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="invtotal" name="invtotal" />

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#invdiscount").on("change", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
    var amount = $("#invamount").val();
    var discount = jQuery("#invdiscount option:selected").attr("data-discount");
    var maths1 = (discount * amount/100);
    jQuery("#invtotal").val(maths1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I added :selected to var discount, changed the listener to on.("change" and I also added .toFixed(2) at the end of the value to display in the input to force 2 decimal places, works a charm, thank you.

Comment: Another improvement might be to extend the selector to `$('#invdiscount,#invamount')`, as this will trigger the calculation whenever the amount or the discount changes.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are doing `sum()` on each **click** on the input.
And you have to do `sum()` each time the **select change**.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#invdiscount").on("change", function() {
        sum();
    });
});
```